# On finding the asymptotic distribution of the coefficient of variation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, normal-distribution

Given an IID sample $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu \ne 0$ let

$$(S_n)^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n ( X_i - \overline{X_n})^2$$

I want to find the distribution of the coefficient of variation $\frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n}$ where $\bar{X}_n$ is the sample mean. I have come up with an entire solution but there appears to be an error I can't find.

**MY SOLUTION**:

$S_n$ is asymptotically consistent for $\sigma \implies \frac{S_n}{\sigma} \xrightarrow{p}1$

Since $ \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)$ converges to a normal distribution (by the central limit theorem)  by the delta method we have that $\sqrt{n} \frac{\sigma}{\bar{X}_n}$ converges in distribution to $$  \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2}Z $$

where $Z \sim N\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}, 1\right) $ this is because we have chosen $\phi(x) = \frac{\sigma}{x} \implies \phi'(x) = -\frac{\sigma}{x^2} $. ($\phi$ is the function we are applying to the sequence of random variables).

Now from Slutsky's theorem we have that $$\sqrt{n} \frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n } = \sqrt{n}\frac{S_n/ \sigma}{\bar{X}_n / \sigma} \xrightarrow{d} N\left( \frac{\sigma}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^4}\right)$$

Except the solution I am given has $N\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu},\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu^2}\right)$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I only read the first half, but it seems the sample mean $\overline{X}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to the constant $\mu$ by the law of large numbers. But you say it converges to a normal distribution, so perhaps you have another definition of $\overline{X}_n$ in mind.

Comment: @Michael I made a mistake, correcting it. I meant that $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n$ converges in distribution to a normal. Thanks

Comment: $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n$ diverges in distribution. Maybe you meant $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)$ instead?

Comment: @NCh correct again. Thanks

Comment: This is the root of all problems: as soon as you correctly write the statement that you need to prove, everything will become obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, 
$\sqrt{n} \frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n }$ diverges in distribution. Since the fraction tends to $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ in probability, and $\sqrt{n}$ tends to infinity, so the product tends to $\pm\infty$ as well.

I suppose that you want to find the limit in distribution of 
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n } - \frac{\sigma}{\mu}\right).$$

So,
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n } - \frac{\sigma}{\mu}\right)=\frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n\right)=\frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \sigma\right) - \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n-\sigma\right)\right).$$

Note that 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n-\sigma\right)\xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^2}\right).
$$
In fact, this value is normally distributed for any $n$, but it does not matter now.

Next, 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \sigma\right)=\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(S^2_n - \sigma^2\right)}{S_n+\sigma}
$$
For the denominator we have $S_n+\sigma \xrightarrow{p} 2\sigma$, and for the numerator the following holds: $\sqrt{n}\left(S^2_n - \sigma^2\right) \xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,2\sigma^4\right)$. Then by Slutsky's theorem we get
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \sigma\right)=\frac{\sqrt{n}\left(S^2_n - \sigma^2\right)}{S_n+\sigma} \xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{2\sigma^4}{(2\sigma)^2}\right) = N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right).
$$
Note that $S_n$ and $\bar X_n$ are independent. Therefore the difference in (\ref{1}) converges in distribution to a difference of two independent normally distributed random variables: 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \sigma\right) - \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n-\sigma\right) \xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2}+\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^2}\right)
$$
Finally, by Slutsky's theorem with $\bar X_n\xrightarrow{p}\mu$, we get:
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{S_n}{\bar{X}_n } - \frac{\sigma}{\mu}\right)=\frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(S_n - \sigma\right) - \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n-\sigma\right)\right)\xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2\mu^2}+\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^4}\right).$$

Comment: Is there a mistake in the point $
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\sigma}{\mu}\bar{X}_n-\sigma\right)\xrightarrow{d} N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^2}\right).
$  since we are subtracting $\sigma$ and not $\mu$. By the way thanks this was a great explanation!

Comment: Find distribution of $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}X_1$ and check.

Comment: The distribution of $\frac{\sigma}{\mu} X_1$ is $N \left( \mu,  \frac{\sigma^4}{ \mu^2}    \right)$ so this leads me to say that there is a mistake? Sorry I guess I am not getting this step.

Comment: The distribution of $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}X_1$ is $N\left(\sigma, \frac{\sigma^4}{\mu^2}\right)$.