# Do the sample coefficients of variation follow a specific distribution when a lot of samples are taken?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance

I am measuring the coefficient of variation after a process takes place, and I do not know the population distribution. I would like to find the probability the coefficient of variation is smaller than a specific value. I know that if I were looking at the sample mean, I would be able to use the central limit theorem if it were large enough. I was wondering if I could use a similar method for the sample coefficients of variation, or whether the coefficients of variation follow a distribution when a large enough set of samples are taken.

Comment: Are you referring to the *sample* coefficient of variation (sample standard deviation divided by sample mean) throughout your question?

Comment: Sorry yes the sample coefficient of variation

Comment: [Wikipedia has some information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Distribution) in the case of sampling from a normal distribution "provided that negative and small positive values of the sample mean occur with negligible frequency", and also points to [McKay's approximation for the coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKay%27s_approximation_for_the_coefficient_of_variation)

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665884/321264.